# Play framework - how to monitor my app thread pools?

Tags: multithreading, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, threadpool

I have reached the point in time where I need to monitor my app performance and understand what is going under the hood.
My application is running on Heroku, so I don't have the option to run the regular `jmap`, `jstack` commands.

I read all Heroku documents talking about performance, and play documentation, but didn't find an answer.

So is there a good way to measure my default execution context thread pool size?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jmap` and `jstack` with the scripts described in this article on [Troubleshooting Memory Issues in Java Applications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues#generating-thread-dumps-in-the-background).

There is also a [memory logging agent](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues#memory-logging-agent) that logs runtime stats in near real time.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried the jmap and jstack scripts. but working with them is not good enough. To enable them (for example jmap) I need to set the jmap interval param. which result in a restart. this means loosing the problematic state I have been at. So I can't really debug my process in production on demand. (Of course leaving this interval is not an option - will make my logs dirty, and most of the time it's not relevant)

Comment: And this will not help me measure the current state of my thread pool over time..:(